# Adding image collection in a list to DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, list, datagridview

I'm trying to add an image collection in a list of images, to a `DataGridView` I already populated with data from Entity Framework.

The image collection was actually generated from "image.jpg" names I stored in the database, I wonder how I could add my image list collection alongside the other data in the `DataGridView`.

Here is the code:

```
quinEntities context1 = new quinEntities();
BindingSource bi = new BindingSource();

var query = from x in context1.studentinfoes
            join y in context1.classinfoes
            on x.classid equals y.classid
                    select new { y.classname, x.surname, x.religion };

bi.DataSource = query.ToList();
dataGridView1.DataSource = bi;

List<Image> mee = new List<Image>();
var passports = context1.studentinfoes.Select(u => u.passport);

foreach (var passport in passports)
{
    Image okk = new Bitmap(passport);
    mee.Add(okk);
}

DataGridViewImageColumn img = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
foreach (var me in mee)
{
    img.Image = me;
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(img);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do it all in one go.

The inner query gets your data from EF, and the first call to `ToList()` executes the EF query.

The outer query then loops over the first result set, creating a new `Bitmap` and adding it to a second anonymous type:

```
quinEntities context1 = new quinEntities();
var query = (from x in
                (from s in context1.studentinfoes
                 join c in context1.classinfoes
                     on s.classid equals c.classid
                 select new
                    {
                        c.classname,
                        s.surname,
                        s.religion,
                        s.passport
                    }).ToList()
             select new
                {
                    x.classname,
                    x.surname,
                    x.religion,
                    passport = new Bitmap(x.passport)
                });

        dataGridView1.DataSource = query.ToList();
```

You don't need the `BindingSource` either, unless you have a specific reason to use it.

Comment: i got this compiler error "Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities."